# why post blog content get by comment?

Tags: python, django

hello i have a problem that when i post a Blog,it is got by both blog and comment, here is the specific:

### problems

when i post a blog, the content goes to Model.Blog.content, but also goes to Model.Comments.content, and save in Mysql database, table Blog and Comments, show in front end either. i think it is there is some problem with the name"content",they are same in Blog and comment model, but not sense about that.

so, pls help, with great appreciate!!!

**url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/',admin.site.urls),
url(r'^blogs/$',get_blogs),
url(r'^detail/(\d+)/$',get_details,name='blog_get_detail'),
url(r'^$', Register, name='register'),
url(r'^register/$',Register,name='register'),
url(r'^blog_post/$',Post_blog,name='blog_post'),
```

**models.py**

```
class Blog(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(verbose_name='标题',max_length=150)
author = models.CharField(verbose_name='作者',max_length=16,blank=True, null=True,default='adma')
# abstract = models.TextField('blog_abstract',blank=True, null=True,max_length=150)
content = models.TextField(verbose_name='内容',max_length=5000)
created = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='发布日期',default=datetime.datetime.now)
catagory = models.ForeignKey(Catagory,related_name="blog_catagory",verbose_name="分类")
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag,related_name="blog_tag",verbose_name="标签")

class Comment(models.Model):
blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog,verbose_name='文章')
name = models.CharField(verbose_name='评论人',max_length=16,blank=True, null=True)
# email = models.EmailField('email')
content = models.TextField(verbose_name='评论内容',max_length=240)
created = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='评论时间',default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

**view.py**

```
def get_details(request,blog_id):
try:
    blog = Blog.objects.get(id=blog_id)
except Blog.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404

if request.method == 'GET':
    form = CommentForm()
else:
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
        cleaned_data['blog'] = blog
        Comment.objects.create(**cleaned_data)

ctx = {
    'blog':blog,
    'comments':blog.comment_set.all().order_by('-created'),
    'form':form
}
return render(request,'blog_details.html',ctx)

def Post_blog(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    bf = BlogForm(request.POST)

    if bf.is_valid():
        post = bf.save(commit=False)
        post.author = request.user
        post.save()
        return get_details(request,blog_id=post.id)
else:
    bf = BlogForm()
return render(request,'blog_post.html',{'bf':bf })
```

**comments template**

```
    {% for comment in comments %}
            <div class="comment-field" style="padding-top:10px;">
                {{ comment.name }} 说：{{ comment }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

**blog_post template**

```
  <form id="blog_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div>
                {{ bf.as_p}}
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="保存并发布">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Post_blog` you have `return get_details(request,blog_id=post.id)`.
This calls get_details with POST request and create new comment.
You should change it to `return redirect('blog_get_detail')` but dont forget to import `redirect` first:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
return redirect('blog_get_detail', post.id)
```

Comment: thank you!!!i didn't get it, this Post_blog is just get the BlogForm's items except comment(is it ? or the foreignkey effect?), why it create a new comment?

Comment: @TimWells `request.POST` contains items from Blog model (including content) so when you calling `get_details` this value passed to `CommentForm` and this creates new comment.